# Jquery - how to alternately unhide and hide multiple nested DIVs individually on-click

Tags: jquery, html, nested, hide, slidetoggle

Im very new to the Jquery language and need to get something done for a site. I want to be able to click on any of the DIVs to hide or unhide. At the moment only the first DIV does that.
My code only works when I change the div `id="boxes"` to `class="boxes"` but I can only use the former. Can you help me to fix this please?

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $(".hidearea").toggle();
      $(".moreinfo").text('More Info');
      $("#boxes").click(function () {

          var index = $(this).index(),

              newTargets = $('.hidearea').eq(index);
              ancTargets = $('.moreinfo').eq(index);
          $(ancTargets).text($(ancTargets).text() == 'More Info' ? 'Less Info' : 'More Info');
          newTargets.slideToggle(300)
          return false;
      })
  });
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="boxwrap">

  <div id="boxes" style="width:400px; min-height:200px; border:thin solid black;"> Visible area    
    <a class="moreinfo" href=""></a>    
    <div class="hidearea" style="width:200px; height:200px; border:thin solid red;">Hidden area     
    </div>  
  </div>

  <div id="boxes" style="width:400px; min-height:200px; border:thin solid black;"> Visible area    
    <a class="moreinfo" href=""></a>    
    <div class="hidearea" style="width:200px; height:200px; border:thin solid red;">Hidden area     
    </div>  
  </div>

  <div id="boxes" style="width:400px; min-height:200px; border:thin solid black;"> Visible area    
    <a class="moreinfo" href=""></a>    
    <div class="hidearea" style="width:200px; height:200px; border:thin solid red;">Hidden area     
    </div>  
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: There only can only be 1 id with the same name in your page, so why using id and not class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you probably know, an ID must be unique per element and can only be used at most once within a document. You're violating those rules by having the same ID on multiple elements (in the same document).

That being said, if you aren't able to change the ID's to classes, you can use an attribute selector:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".hidearea").toggle();
  $(".moreinfo").text('More Info');
  $("[id='boxes']").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var index = $(this).index(),
          newTargets = $('.hidearea').eq(index),
          ancTargets = $('.moreinfo').eq(index);
      $(ancTargets).text($(ancTargets).text() == 'More Info' ? 'Less Info' : 'More Info');
      newTargets.slideToggle(300)
      return false;
  })
});
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5R7hL/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. "[id='boxes']" worked for me.